# time.now on validates_timeliness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a datatime and I'm trying to set in my models that the user can only choose datatime greater than or equal to today's datatime. I am using the validates_timeliness gem as follows:

```
validates_datetime :data, :on_or_after => lambda { Time.now }
```

But when I fill in the form with the date it only accepts if a datatime is assigned with 3 hours more than the current datatime. My version is 5.0.2

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try `Time.zone.now`

Comment: I tried, but it made the same mistake.

Comment: Just to be sure, does your console return proper expected time for `Time.zone.now`?

Comment: I think this is a problem, the console is showing Time.zone.now a value of +3 hours. How do I edit this? Thank you!

Comment: What is this set as in your config? `config.default_timezone` or `config.time_zone`

Comment: config.time_zone = 'UTC' in application.rb

Comment: Try restarting server and console, also change it to `default_timezone` if that doean't work and restart is necessary..both console and server. PS. Hope your local system's time is proper too.. ;)

Comment: I removed the config.time_zone = 'utc' and put config.default_timezone =: local, and it keeps marking the same time. Is this location to pick up my computer time?

Comment: What do u mean by `it keeps marking the same time.`?

Comment: That the same thing continues, the time remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it has something to do with the time zone of the application.

Open Rails console, then type:

```
Time.zone.to_s
```

And then maybe it's a `GMT - 3` (or something like that)